# Patching in a custom StandardValues provider

Tags: configuration

I am trying to add a custom StandardValues provider to a Sitecore 8.1 site (8.1.0 rev 160519) and I am not having a good time.

To do this I reflected the standard Sitecore.Data.StandardValuesProvider in Sitecore.Kernel, copied all the codez and made the change I want. It compiles, so I assume it'll work :D

*btw* I am modifying the behaviour of `private SafeDictionary<ID, string> GetStandardValues(Item item)`, for reasons

I attempt to wire up the patch thusly: -

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <providers>
        <add name="sitecore">
          <patch:attribute name="type">[REDACTED].Web.Sitecore.Providers.[REDACTED]StandardValuesProvider, [REDACTED].Web</patch:attribute>
        </add>
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But although my patch looks like it's worked in /showconfig.aspx, the site itself doesn't load: -

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unexpected provider type: 

[REDACTED].Web.Sitecore.Providers.[REDACTED]StandardValuesProvider

Expected: Sitecore.Data.StandardValuesProvider
```

Kind of like.. it doesn't want to see another kind of provider besides the default one ?

Has anyone tried to do this and succeeded ?

Comment: Are you missing some Interface implementations? Will it work if you inherit the default?

Comment: There's no interface to inherit; my class inherits from the base System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderBase in the same way the StandardValuesProvider does, and I've literally copied all the code from StandardValuesProvider, pasted it in and changed the implementation of one method. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong patching the config, but I'm puzzled as to what (it all looks pretty basic). Thx for suggestions though :)

Comment: Have you tried inheriting `Sitecore.Data.StandardValuesProvider` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kasper Gadensgaard mentioned in the comments, the `StandardValuesManager` requires a provider *inherited* from the `StandardValuesProvider` class:

```
public static class StandardValuesManager
{
    private static readonly ProviderHelper<StandardValuesProvider, StandardValuesProviderCollection> _helper = 
        new ProviderHelper<StandardValuesProvider, StandardValuesProviderCollection>("standardValues");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Had to copy a bunch of private methods from the `StandardValuesManager` into my subclass (urgh), but this worked - thanks :^)